# Is it possible to use IdentityModel to integrate a webform app in .net 4.5 with IdentityServer4 without using OWIN?

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms, owin, identityserver4, identityserver3

I have a WebForm Application in .net framework 4.5 an IdentityServer4 implementation in .net core 2.1.

OWIN it is outdated or deprecated/ My question is: Is it possible to use IdentityModel to integrate that webform app with IdentityServer4 without using OWIN?

What is the best path that I need to get to reach my objective of integrating my webform app with IdentityServer4?

Thank's in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MVC manual sample - that demonstrates how to do a sign in without using OWIN middleware. Should be easy to modify to use with webforms.