# How to manually validate identityserver accesstoken on the client side

Tags: c#, identityserver4, identitymodel

I posted a question some time ago: [Is it possible to use IdentityModel to integrate a webform app in .net 4.5 with IdentityServer4 without using OWIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282303/is-it-possible-to-use-identitymodel-to-integrate-a-webform-app-in-net-4-5-with)
. I almost did that integration manually. Now, I have some more questions: Do I need to validate an AccessToken against id_token like in the specs here : [OpenID Connect Core 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#HybridTokenValidation) in

> 3.3.2.9.  Access Token Validation section.

If yes, How can I manually do this validation? I know how to validate the AccessToken in insolate way, using ValidateToken() from JwtSecurityTokenHandler in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, but I don't know how to validate it together with the id_token using "at_hash".

Is there any library in .net framework 4.7.1 that can be used for that?

Comment: Check if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#validating-tokens

Comment: @rad I'm going to check it